# Преобразовать полное ФИО в краткое

Tags: c#, wpf

При вводе в `TextBox` полного ФИО (Астапенко Валерий Максимович) требуется в другом выводить фимилию и инициалы (Астапенко В.М.).

Comment: И в чем, собственно, трудность? Что не получается?

Comment: Комбинация функций split (разделить по пробелу), join (обьеденить массив), subString (Оставить один символ), replace...

Comment: Не забывайте про составные имена, где пробелов может быть больше 2.

Comment: @Monk, задача поставлена в том виде, в котором поставлена, не пытайтесь на ходу внести какие-то другие идеи. Во многом потому, что суть вопроса в основном не в правилах сокращения имён до ФИО, что в общем-то совсем не компетенция этого ресурса.

Comment: @AntonPapin внести другие идеи? Я просто пишу, что простой split и чтение 1 и 2 индексов и получение их инициалов - некорректное решение.

Comment: Простой сплит - корректное решение для случая, описанного в вопросе. Для остальных случаев могут понадобиться другие решения, но вы же не будете отвечать на вопрос о психологии, отвечая на вопрос по математике?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берём два текстбокса, связываем:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="TbxFullName"/>
 <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="TbxFullName">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <myNamespace:FIOConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

Код конвертера:

```
public class FIOConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var split = ((string)value).Split(' ');
        return split.First() + " " +
               string.Join(" ",
                            split.Skip(1)
                            .Select(s => string.Format("{0}.", s.First())));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: ругается на `string.Join(' ',`

Comment: Двойные ковычки нужны

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, не было под рукой IDE, писал прямо в ответ.

Comment: @AntonPapin зачем молодые умы губишь?) обленятся же

Comment: @МаксимКутовой если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, то поддержите автора, нажав на зеленую галочку возле ответа

Comment: Да кто против...